# Why is the movie named "Behind the Candelabra"?

Tags: title, behind-the-candelabra

While I realise that the Liberace biopic, [Behind the Candelabra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behind_the_Candelabra), is based on Scott Thorson's book of the same name, what is the meaning of the title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Liberace pretty much [always had a candelabra](https://www.google.com/search?q=liberace%20piano&safe=active&client=firefox&hs=VvM&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=tvdWUr_vAdCuyAG15YEI&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1600&bih=707&dpr=1) on or near his piano while playing, as he was known for his very elaborate and often flamboyant stage presence. As such "Behind the Candelabra" is a play on the phrase "Behind the Scenes", but it refers to his frequent use of candelabras in his performances.